# How can I refer to my two dimensional boolean array as a whole?

Tags: java

The 2d boolean is a static variable if that means anything. I thought that I could refer to just the name of the array, but I get an error for doing that.

```
public class Game {

static boolean[][] board = new boolean[3][3];
}

public class Computer
{
  if (Game.board = true)
    {
        //code
    }
}
```

Comment: you want to check if all elements in your array are true?

Comment: Be careful - aside from the issue at hand, you're using the assignment operator `=` in your `if` condition. Use `==` to test equality between primitives. Also, for `boolean`s, you can just write `if (someBoolean)` for example.

Comment: @DougRamsey Yes, that's what I wanted it to do. PaulBellora I've tried that already, and I still got an error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`if(Game.board = true)` will throw a compiler error because `board` is a two-dimensional array and thus cannot be assigned a single `boolean` value.

Also, when **comparing** make sure you use the comparison operator `==`

Perhaps, you want to do something like:

`if(Game.board[i][j] == true)` where `i` and `j` are indexing the array:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
    {
        if(board[i][j] == true)
        {
          // Code
        }
    }
}
```

You have `board` declared as `static`, any particular reason?

Since `board[i][j]` returns a `boolean` value, there really isn't a need for the `== true`:

```
if(board[i][j])
```

Comment: Well, I tried to declare board as an instance variable, but it wouldn't let me, so I just used static instead.

Comment: The code in if block will be executed as soon as it finds true, I thought OP wants to check if all the elements are true

Comment: @igknighton: It is important to know the difference between static and non-static, and when to use which. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7026507/why-are-static-variables-considered-evil

Comment: @AbdullahShaikh: The OP can easily modify this code to check for all elements. I am simply offering a helping hand.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, `Game.board` is how you refer to the `boolean[][]` two-dimensional array.  But what makes you think you can compare a 3x3 array of `boolean`s to `true` directly?

Answer (score 1):

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
   for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++)
      if(board[i][j] == true){

         //Code

      }
```

Comment: The OP wants to check if all elements are `true`, not set them to `true`.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you are looking for something like this?

```
import java.util.Arrays;

class Test
{
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        boolean[][] board = {{}, {}, {}};
        // all values in board are set to false by default

        boolean[][] board2 = new boolean[0][3];
        boolean[][] board3 = {{true},{true},{true, false, false}};
        boolean[][] board4 = {{}, {true}, {true, true}, {}};

        printInfo(board, 1);
        printInfo(board2, 2);
        printInfo(board3, 3);
        printInfo(board4, 4);


    }

    public static boolean check(boolean[][] board)
    {
        if(board.length == 0) return false;

        int colLength = 0;
        int elementsInBoard = 0;    

        for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++)
        {
            colLength = board[i].length;
            elementsInBoard += colLength;
            for(int j = 0; j < colLength; j++)
            {
                if (board[i][j] == false)
                {
                    return false;
                }
            }
        }

        if (elementsInBoard == 0)
        {
            return false;
        }else
        {
            return true;
        }
    }

    public static void printInfo(boolean[][] board, int id)
    {
        System.out.println("Board : " + id);
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(board)); 
        System.out.println(check(board));       
    }
}
```

Output:

```
Board : 1
[[], [], []]
false
Board : 2
[]
false
Board : 3
[[true], [true], [true, false, false]]
false
Board : 4
[[], [true], [true, true], []]
true
```

Comment: What if boolean[][] board = new boolean[0][3];

Comment: @AchintyaJha, you are right of course, it was just my lazy implementation assuming that the board was square or rectangle.

Comment: @AchintyaJha, You removed your last comment, and I thought that your point was totally valid. Did I miss anything?

Comment: I removed my last comment because I just wrote it and after that I start thinking it will work or not. Anyway I think getting number of columns in each row if given 2d array is not square or rectangle should work fine.

Comment: @AchintyaJha, yes that works fine. But I also can't check to see if all cell are empty the way I used to `board.length * board[0].length`. I think I addressed this too.

Answer (score 0):

You declared your variable `board` as a 2D array of boolean and you also initialize it.
    static boolean[][] board = new boolean[3][3];

Now here, `Game.board = true`, you are trying to assign your 2D boolean array variable to a boolean value that is incorrect.

Answer (score 0):

A) Code like this is a bug:

```
if (someBoolean = true)
```

You have just silently *set* the boolean variable instead of testing it. You want:

```
if (someBoolean == true)
```

or better yet:

```
if (someBoolean)
```

B) A `boolean[][]` (an array of array of boolean) is not a boolean. Try this:

```
if (Game.board[x][y])
```

Answer (score 0):

A couple issues with your code. First, you can't directly compare a `boolean[][]` with `true`. You'll need to use a loop. Second, you have to place code statements inside a method. You can't use things like if statements without a method. Here's an example of what you want:

```
public class Game {
    private boolean[] board = new boolean[3][3];

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        boolean allTrue = true;
        for (int i = 0; i < board.length; i++) {
            boolean[] row = board[i];
            for (int j = 0; j < row.length; j++) {
                allTrue &= row[j];
            }
        }
        System.out.println(allTrue);
    }
}
```

This ignores some short circuit logic you could do, but hopefully you get the point.

One last thing, a single `=` is assignment, not comparison. Use `==` for comparison, such as `myInt == 1`.